# How to tell if a VG is clustered?

Tags: cluster, pacemaker

I have a CentOS 7 Pacemaker cluster with GFS2 Filesystrems mounted.  I'm fairly certain that `vgchange -cy vg_name` was NOT run during setup.  I tried running `vgchange --test -cy vg_name` and it tells me the volume group is already clustered.

In Linux 6 `service clvmd status` will show if the vg is clustered or not.  However on Linux 7 `pcs resource show clvmd` output is quite different and I'm not sure what to look for.

```
pcs resource show clvmd
     Resource: clvmd (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=clvm)
     Operations: monitor interval=30s on-fail=fence (clvmd-monitor-interval-30s)

start interval=0s timeout=90s (clvmd-start-interval-0s)
stop interval=0s timeout=90s (clvmd-stop-interval-0s)
```

Would creating the filesystem resources have done the vgchange if needed?  Is there anything else I can check?

Answer (score 0):

This is displayed in the 6th attribute field shown in the output of `vgs`. Let me quote from the `vgs` man page below.

> ```
>    The vg_attr bits are:
>
>    1  Permissions: (w)riteable, (r)ead-only
>
>    2  Resi(z)eable
>
>    3  E(x)ported
>
>    4  (p)artial: one or more physical volumes belonging to the volume group are missing from the system
>
>    5  Allocation policy: (c)ontiguous, c(l)ing, (n)ormal, (a)nywhere
>
>    6  (c)lustered, (s)hared
> ```